# python wait and retry current iteration

Tags: python

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I am iteratively pulling data from the GitHub API to get the names and organizations of some repositories

```
for i in repoID:  #get names of repos
    response= requests.get('https://api.github.com/repositories/{}'.format(i),headers=headers)
    print(i)
    if 'full_name' in response.json():
        repokey[str(i)]=response.json()['full_name']
    else : 
        print('ratelimit reached for {}, waiting 120 sec'.format(i))
        time.sleep(120)
        continue
```

It's waiting for a set amount of time before continuing to the next iteration.
but I want to retry the current iteration where the API rate limit was reached after waiting.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `while` instead of iterating through the components themselves, that way you can just go back.

```
i = 0
while i < len(repoID):
    previously_i = repoID[i]
    # your stuff
    i+=1

    if limit:
        i-=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like this one:

```
from urllib3 import BaseHTTPResponse, Retry
import time

class GitHubRetry(Retry):
    def get_retry_after(self, response: BaseHTTPResponse) -> float | None:
        if 'X-RateLimit-Remaining' in response.headers and 'X-RateLimit-Reset' in response.headers:
            remaining_requests = int(response.headers['X-RateLimit-Remaining'])
            if remaining_requests > 0:
                return None
            else:
                reset_time = int(response.headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'])
                current_time = int(time.time())
                return float(reset_time - current_time)
        return None
```

You can use it via

```
API_TOKEN = ...
http_session = requests.session()
http_session.headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'whatever/1.0',
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github+json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {API_TOKEN}',
})

retries = GitHubRetry(total=2,
            connect=2,
            backoff_factor=2,
            status_forcelist=[401, 402, 403, 404, 413, 429, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504],
            backoff_jitter=10,
)

http_session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

for repo_name in repos:
    response = http_session.get(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_name}')
```

I shared the code on [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/michaeldorner/9a7c852c1ae2bdfcd088157c7e5d8045).